# django-rest-framework: globally restrict requests to GET?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework and I would like to to allow only GET requests to my API.

Is there some global setting for this?

Currently I'm decorating individual views, like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def my_api_view(request, format=None):
    # get data
```

Comment: If Rahul Gupta's answer below solved the problem, it would be nice to reward his time by marking it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 5):

**You can write a [custom Permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) `IsRequestMethodGet` which will grant access to only `GET` requests.**

To implement the  custom permission `IsRequestMethodGet`, override the `BasePermission` class and implement `.has_permission(self, request, view)` method. The method should return `True` if the request should be granted access, and `False` otherwise.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsRequestMethodGet(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    The request is a GET request.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method == 'GET' # Returns True if GET request
```

So, a request will be granted access if the request method is `GET`, otherwise not.

Now, you need to include this custom permission class in your global settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'my_app.permissions.IsRequestMethodGet',
    )
}
```